# example of convergence to exponential type of function

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory

I want to prove the existence of $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\bigg| \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{a_k}{x^k} \right) - \exp \left( \dfrac{\sin(e^x)}{\sqrt{x}} \right) \bigg| \leq 10^{-6}, \quad \forall x \in [1,\infty).$$

I was thinking on trying Darboux's Riemann integrable definition, or some kind of root/ratio test. I am sorry not giving some work, but I am really without a clue on how to solve this one.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With a suitable change of variable, we are just looking for a polynomial approximation $p(x)$ of
$$ f(x)=\exp\left(\sqrt{x}\sin e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right) $$
over the interval $I=(0,1]$, such that $\|p-f\|_{\infty}\leq 10^{-6}$.

Despite the wild behaviour of $f(x)$ on I:

[image: A continuous function with a wild behaviour]

$f(x)$ is still a continuous function over $I$, hence [Weierstrass' approximation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassApproximationTheorem.html) is enough to ensure the existence of $p(x)$.